# the use of `setTimeout` in the code below?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I notice that when I remove `setTimeout` from the code below, the animation stops working. Can someone explain to me what's happening under the hood?

Why is it necessary to insert this `setTimeout` here, even though the time value is `0`? In my mind, it should execute right away, so why insert `setTimeout(cb,0)`?

```
setTimeout(() => {
... //see below for code
}, 0);


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    .message-ball {
      font-size: 20px;
      line-height: 200px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .circle {
      transition-property: width, height, margin-left, margin-top;
      transition-duration: 2s;
      position: fixed;
      transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
      background-color: red;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <button onclick="go()">Click me</button>

  <script>

  function go() {
    showCircle(150, 150, 100, div => {
      div.classList.add('message-ball');
      div.append("Hello, world!");
    });
  }

  function showCircle(cx, cy, radius, callback) {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.width = 0;
    div.style.height = 0;
    div.style.left = cx + 'px';
    div.style.top = cy + 'px';
    div.className = 'circle';
    document.body.append(div);

    setTimeout(() => {
      div.style.width = radius * 2 + 'px';
      div.style.height = radius * 2 + 'px';

      div.addEventListener('transitionend', function handler() {
        div.removeEventListener('transitionend', handler);
        callback(div);
      });
    }, 0);
  }
  </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful) question

Comment: @charlietfl this is not a duplicate. the answer is addressed by Jonas Wilms below, which is more specific than the duplicate you described.

Comment: The essential reasoning is the same

Comment: @charlietfl the question you introduced is more general, and this is a more specific example.

Comment: The reasoning is not the same @charlietfl. In this piece of code, i'm making changes to `style.width` and `style.height`, and this is why I need the additional `setTimeout`, whereas the reasoning in the duplicate question, is a more general, non-specific, explanation, ie "browser cooperative multitasking", which is not the case here.

Comment: Still comes down to browser needing time for inital render so while the other is a bit more general the explanation is well written and explains a little more what's happening under the hood so both do go together. Is not a negative having that other link here

Comment: @charlietfl OK got it! I thought this question is closed once a duplicate question is linked to this one, but it seems like it can still be found here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because *transitions* only happen when a property was changed. If you do

```
 div.style.width = 0;
 div style.width = "1000px";
```

That wil not animate anything as the property was directly changed. If you defer the second update, it will detect the change and cause a transition to happen.,